# Spring problems integrating ActiveMQ inside Liferay

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, liferay-6, spring-jms

I'm modifying a Maven-based Liferay portlet (6.1.1) that uses Service Layer.

My needs are to add an ActiveMQ listener to the portlet (for communication with external products).

I'm trying to use integrated spring engine (3.0.7) to instance the listener.

So, to start, inside ext-sping.xml (auto managed by Liferay) I defined the following beans:
- a connection factory: `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory`
- a caching connection factory (`org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory`) with `targetConnectionFactory` reference to previous bean.

At deploying time the error I get is:

```
Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory] to 
required type [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory] for property 
'targetConnectionFactory': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Obviusly `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` implements `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory`, infact if I try to set the value by code, the deploy is done succesfully.

In my *pom.xml* I try to add a depenency both to activemq-core (just activemq) or activemq-all (contains also *javax.jms* package), but without success.

How it is possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Possibly a classloader problem - the classloader loading the `CachingConnectionFactory` is resolving to a different `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` to the one loading the ActiveMQ factory.

Run with `-verbose` on the command line to see which jar(s) classes are being loaded from.

Comment: Yes... infact another jms.jar file exists inside tomcat lib folder. But does it exist a way to force classloader or classloading options?